# How to add records from an HTML table data taken from a table model into another table model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

First at all something about me... I'm just a beginner Python and Django developer, so I'm learning and applying what I have learned in my real work project.

## The problem

I'm building an small Pharmacy Management Application for the hospital where I work and I want to make there a medicines availability tracklist where doctors can check if a medicine is available or not in order they can write patient prescriptions.

## What I have been done?

I have a table model for the National Drugs Formulary (Formulario Nacional de Medicamentos), the complete list of all drugs and pharmacologic products used in my country (Cuba) described in my Django models.py as:

```py
class FarmMedicamento(models.Model):
    meddesc = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    presentacion = models.ForeignKey(FarmPresentacion, models.DO_NOTHING)
    forma_presentacion = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s - %s %s" % (self.meddesc, str(self.presentacion).upper(), self.forma_presentacion))

    def propiedad_colname(self):
        return ("%s - %s %s" % (self.meddesc, str(self.presentacion).upper(), self.forma_presentacion))

    propiedad_colname.short_description = 'Medicamento'

    columna_medicamento = property(propiedad_colname)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'farm_medicamento'
        verbose_name = "Medicamento"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Medicamentos'
```

I store the medicine availability in another table model described as:

```py
class FarmExistencia(models.Model):

    medid = models.OneToOneField(FarmMedicamento, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True, verbose_name="Medicamento")
    disponible = models.BooleanField("Disponible")
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'farm_existencia'
        verbose_name = "Disponibilidad de medicamento"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Disponibilidad de medicamentos'

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s" % (self.medid))
```

The medicine list view is:

```py
class FarmMedicamentoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = FarmMedicamento
    context_object_name = 'listado_fnm'
    template_name = 'existencias/farmmedicamento_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FarmMedicamentoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['disponibles'] = FarmExistencia.disponibles.all()
        context['agotados'] = FarmExistencia.agotados.all()
        return context
```

## What I want?

I want to add new medicines availables pressing the plus button at the main list and update the green div of "Availables medicines" immediately, but I don't know how to do that.

Screenshot of my actual template list at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlW6h.png

## HTML of template

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}AllenFarma | Listado de medicamentos {% endblock title %}
{% block head %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/datatables.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="{% static 'js/datatables.min.js' %}"></script>
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    .table > tbody > tr > td.item_add-control {
        background: url('/static/images/icons/add_button.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
    }
    .table > tbody > tr > td.item_remove-control {
        background: url('/static/images/icons/remove_button.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
    }
    </style>
{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div style="text-align:left" class="panel-title">Medicamentos en existencia</div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px" class="panel-body">
                {% include 'existencias_list.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div style="text-align:left" class="panel-title">Medicamentos agotados</div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px" class="panel-body">
                {% include 'agotados_list.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">    
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div style="text-align:left" class="panel-title">Medicamentos del Formulario Nacional de Medicamentos</div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px" class="panel-body">
                <table id="listado_medicametos" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Medicamentos</th>
                            <th>Presentación</th>
                            <th>Forma de presentación</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for medicamento in listado_fnm %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{medicamento.meddesc}}</td>
                        <td>{{medicamento.presentacion}}</td>
                        <td>{{medicamento.forma_presentacion}}</td>
                        <td id="add_control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#listado_medicametos')
        .dataTable({
            "columns": [
                {"data": "meddesc"},
                {"data": "presentacion"},
                {"data": "forma_presentacion"},
                {
                    "class":          "item_add-control",
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ""
                },
            ],
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "language": {
                "url": "/static/i18n/es_ES.json"
            },
            scrollY: 230
        });
});
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: By immediately do you mean without a refresh of the page?

Comment: Yeah preferably without a page refresh! but any other solution it's also welcome.

Comment: Que bola asere!!!  Mira ... You'll need some js work for achieving what you want. If you can live with page refreshing you only need to reload the same view after adding the medicine.

Let me ask, what have you tried, how are you adding the new medicines?

Comment: @Raydel Miranda I'm working in a form right now to add the new available medicines just for learn how to do in that way, but right now I don't have none... only the form of Djando Admin interface. Remember that I'm not an expert, I'm just a Django beginner guy. (Sorry my English it's awful)

Comment: Based on your requirement, it's unclear why you store the medicine availability in a separate model with a one-to-one relationship. You could specify medicine availability in a field in the FarmMedicamento model instead and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic workflow for a problem like this could be an Ajax call to POST your changes to your Django server, a Django view to receive and implement the change in your models and respond to the Ajax call, which in turn updates the HTML based on whatever update you do.

A simple example:

**Javascript:**

You need an Ajax method which triggers when you click add/remove button and POSTs the medicine's ID to a Django view, where you can set it to available/unavailable.

```
$('.addButton').on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url : '/add/medicine/url/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {'medicine_id': id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'your csrftoken' },
        success: function(json) {
            // Successful response, so you can update the medicine list HTML using JQuery here.
        },
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def add_medicine(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        medicine_id = int(request.POST.get('medicine_id'))
        medicine = Medicine.objects.get(id=medicine_id)
        medicine.available = True
        medicine.save()
        return JsonResponse({'medicine_id': medicine_id}, status=200)
```

This is an example to illustrate the workflow, the naming doesn't match your code. Also, I think you should specify medicine availability in the medicine model itself, rather than in two separate models, or at least have some back ref relationship between the two models, so that you can access one through the other and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add the new medicine via admin interface and get the list  refreshed automaticaly, you must write a Javascript function that loads the data  and populate the list of available medicine.

That JS function should be executed periodicaly (use a timer) and call a Django view that provides the data you want to show there.